# Django models are not ajax serializable

Tags: ajax, django, json, django-models, django-views

I have a simple view that I'm using to experiment with AJAX.

```
def get_shifts_for_day(request,year,month,day):

    data= dict()
    data['d'] =year
    data['e'] = month
    data['x'] = User.objects.all()[2]

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

This returns the following:

```
TypeError at /sched/shifts/2009/11/9/

<User: someguy> is not JSON serializable
```

If I take out the data['x'] line so that I'm not referencing any models it works and returns this:

```
{"e": "11", "d": "2009"}
```

Why can't simplejson parse my one of the default django models?  I get the same behavior with any model I use.

Comment: ambiguous question, not actually a question in the title of the question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just need to add, in your `.dumps` call, a `default=encode_myway` argument to let `simplejson` know what to do when you pass it data whose types it does not know -- the answer to your "why" question is of course that you haven't *told* poor `simplejson` what to DO with one of your models' instances.

And of course you need to write `encode_myway` to provide JSON-encodable data, e.g.:

```
def encode_myway(obj):
  if isinstance(obj, User):
    return [obj.username,
            obj.firstname,
            obj.lastname,
            obj.email]
    # and/or whatever else
  elif isinstance(obj, OtherModel):
    return [] # whatever
  elif ...
  else:
    raise TypeError(repr(obj) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Basically, JSON knows about VERY elementary data types (strings, ints and floats, grouped into dicts and lists) -- it's YOUR responsibility as an application programmer to match everything else into/from such elementary data types, and in `simplejson` that's typically done through a function passed to `default=` at `dump` or `dumps` time.

Alternatively, you can use the `json` serializer that's part of Django, see [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/serialization/).

Comment: can't django be smart enough to know what properties really matters (of course based on what properties the user have defined in the model) to the end user and cut this pain in the a## by default?